# How to add meta description in this Angular 6 index.html?

Tags: html, angular, angular6

There is only one static page for which SEO should be done. I see a title here but not sure how can I add a description as well?

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Site Title</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 2):

On the index.html you can set `<meta name="description" content="">` in the `<head>` section of the page.

Import Meta: `import { Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';`

In the component where you would like to change the description you can inject `Meta`:

```
constructor(private meta: Meta) { }
```

And update the value:

```
this.meta.updateTag({ name: 'description', content: 'Your new description' });
```

Check the docs about the meta service:
https://angular.io/api/platform-browser/Meta

Answer (score 1):

Start by importing the Meta and Title services:

```
import { Component } from '@angular/core';
import { Title, Meta } from '@angular/platform-browser';
```

Inject services into component constructor:

`constructor(private titleService: Title, private metaService: Meta) {}`

add OnInit method and rebuild your app:

```
  ngOnInit() {
    this.titleService.setTitle(this.title);
    this.metaService.addTags([
      {name: 'keywords', content: 'Angular, Universal, Example'},
      {name: 'description', content: 'Angular Universal Example'},
      {name: 'robots', content: 'index, follow'}
    ]);
  }
```

see this link to learn more about meta:

[Getting & Setting HTML Meta Tags in Angular](https://alligator.io/angular/meta-tags/)

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way would be to add it in HTML directly.

```
<!doctype html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>Site Title</title>
  <base href="/">
  <meta
     name="description"
     content=" YOUR DESCPRITION "
  />
  <link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webapp" />

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
</head>
<body>
  <app-root></app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

You can add a manifest file and support it for further enhancement.

Comment: Will this solution work with Angular? I am asking it because by default it didn't provide any metadata when you create a project with CLI

Comment: yes, it will work without any issues. I used it in my previous project and google picked it.

Comment: Testing now. Is this line required?
<link rel="manifest" href="manifest.webapp" />
Also do I need to create that file?

Comment: If you want to add your webpage to the home screen in a mobile device or turn it into PWA then it would be required to add it.

Comment: I mean should I create that file from scratch or it's already in Angular generated project?

Comment: You have to create it by yourself.

Comment: It will work but what if you want to change the language dynamically? Please check Sadaf Niknam answer and Angular SSR

Answer (score 1):

Use these type to update meta description ("description", "my description")